# Cannot build Qt5 on Windows for BlackBerry 10

Tags: c++, qt, blackberry-10

I'm trying to build Qt5 on Windows for the BlackBerry 10 NDK using the source from gitorious following the instructions provided in http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building-Qt5-for-Blackberry. But when I run the command:

```
configure -prefix C:\Users\Eli\development\qt5 -platform blackberry-armv7le-qcc -opengl es2 -nomake examples -nomake tests -opensource -confirm-license -release
```

It starts to compile until I get this error:

```
c:/Users/Eli/development/qt5/qtbase/include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/global/qt_w
indows.h:71:21: fatal error: windows.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
cc: C:/bbndk/gold/host_10_1_0_132/win32/x86/usr/lib/gcc/arm-unknown-nto-qnx8.0.0
eabi/4.6.3/cc1plus caught signal 1
gmake: *** [qfilesystemengine_win.o] Error 1
```

Actually, the `windows.h` file isn't there. Why is this happening? Cloning files from repo didn't return any errors, so I think this is not the problem with the missing file. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Are you still having this issue?

Answer (score 0):

`windows.h` comes with Visual Studio/Platform SDK, it's not part of the Qt source tree. But you're trying to build for BlackBerry so it shouldn't be needed.

Looking at your configure command, shouldn't the second parameter be `-xplatform` and not `-platform`?

Comment: Hi Ionut, thanks for your answer. If a run the command with `-xplatform` I get this:

`The build script does not currently recognize all
platforms supported by Qt.
Rerun this script with a -platform option listed to
set the system/compiler combination you use.` That's why i'm using the `-platform` parameter.

Comment: If a comment the include for `windows.h` in the qt_windows.h file and then run the command, the error I get is: `c:/Users/Eli/development/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/io/qfilesystemengine_win.cpp:60:
22: fatal error: direct.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
cc: C:/bbndk/gold/host_10_1_0_132/win32/x86/usr/lib/gcc/arm-unknown-nto-qnx8.0.0
eabi/4.6.3/cc1plus caught signal 1
gmake: *** [qfilesystemengine_win.o] Error 1`

Comment: The problem is not caused by the Qt source code, so don't make changes to it. It appears it's actually trying to build for Windows and not for BB (using `windows.h` and also mentioning `qfilesystemengine_win.o`). Going back to those parameters, try to leave xplatform as is, and add a `-platform win32-g++`

Comment: When I run the command with both `-xplatform ...` and `-platform win32-g++` options, a pop-up appears telling me that gmake.exe stopped working.

Comment: I'll get to a Windows machine in a couple of hours and give it a try, I don't know what else to say at the moment. Except trying to run configure.bat instead of configure, if you haven't done so already.

Comment: Hi, Ionut. Did you give it a try?

Comment: Yes, I eventually managed to get to it, sorry for the delay. Apparently I was wrong, it does need Windows SDK to be installed because during the configure process it rebuilds configure.exe from sources. Installing Windows SDK on the machine should fix the original errors related to it not finding `windows.h`. It might also fix the platform detection issue, as I was able to run the original configure, with -xplatform and without -platform.